# how to deploy javafx application with sqlite database(preferably using inno script)

Tags: sqlite, deployment, javafx, fxml

I want to deploy a javafx fxml application. I have used sqlite3 database. I tried deploying it using inno script by adding .db file, the first login page shows up but after i enter the credentials and Log-in the window just collapses. I think its because of an exception which I have not programmed to display in a pop window. The programs works just fine when i run in netbeans. Please suggest the best way to deploy an fxml application with sqlite database.

The contents of the project :

1. main project files
2. images in a separate folder named images(background image is displayed in login page)
3. database file.

**EDIT**

I believe the problem was the missing driver. It was not able to connect to the .db file. so I added the following lines to the code where it is connecting to the Database

```
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin_users (ID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, USERNAME TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,PASSWORD TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)");
```

and

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO admin_users (ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1,'admin','xxxxx') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT USERNAME from admin_users WHERE USERNAME= 'admin') LIMIT 1");
```

Now it is creating a database file where I execute the jar. It is going past the login page and everything works fine. But, when I deploy the project using Inno Script. Same problem persists and the application force closes when I click submit.

Comment: One more question, when you install your aplication with inno script, the db file is copied as well?

Comment: yes the DB file is copied but still no luck getting passed the login page.

Comment: Do you encounter an exception? Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: Yep , Exception would be helpful, and the code segment where you initialize the datasource (or connection). And you have to verify that, when the inno script installs the application, the sqlite-jdbc-x.x.x.jar is in your library directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should provide more information, i.e. the exception from the logs. But based on that the screen shows up and the login fails, it could be a database error. I created a Javafx application lately with sqlite db, and I used Spring for the initialization of the DataSource object. This was the bean definition(If you don't use Spring, it could be still useful to compare it to your connection string).

```
<bean id="sqlliteDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:databasefile.db" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

I believe the problem can be either the connection string or a missing driver, but without the exception, I can't tell that.

Comment: I'm sorry for a very late reply. Yes when I enter the credintials(username and password) it shows a `ClassNotFoundException`. It is actually displaying this `org.sqlite.JDBC` in the dialog box .

Comment: That means the SQLite JDBC jar file is not on the classpath. Could you verify the sqlite-jdbc-x.x.x.jar is in your library directory after install. + if you check your application jar file, there has to be a manifest file that contains the list of jar files that is included on the classpath. The jar file has to be on that list too.

Comment: hey gaRos . Thanks a lot for your comment.When I saw the manifest file it was showing `lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar` but there was no lib directory where I have installed the application, When I added it manually to that directory it worked.